# How an Kotlin conversion is done for this method

Tags: kotlin

I am having a method like this in java which returns Object

```
private static Object invokeMethod(Object target, String methodName, Class<?>[] parameterClasses, Object[] paramterValues)
            throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        Class<?> clazz = target.getClass();
        Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, parameterClasses);
        return method.invoke(target, paramterValues);
    }
```

and when I convert it into kotlin I am not getting how an array of class in written in kotlin

I got something like this

```
 @Throws(IllegalAccessException::class, NoSuchMethodException::class, IllegalArgumentException::class, InvocationTargetException::class)
    private fun invokeMethod(target: Any, methodName: String, parameterClasses: Array<Class<*>>?, paramterValues: Array<Any>?): Any {
        val clazz = target.javaClass
        val method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, *parameterClasses)
        return method!!.invoke(target, paramterValues)
    }
```

where *parameterClasses --> It is a spread function in kotlin

[Bluetooth Wrapper Gists](https://gist.github.com/ankittale/2ced2beef7222b47308343559b089c19)

Comment: It is an array of class as you can see a syntax : parameterClasses: Array<Class<*>>?, Here ? means array of a class parameter can be null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the spread operator with nullable types such as `Array<Class<*>>?`. Consider the following change:

```
private fun invokeMethod(
    target: Any,
    methodName: String,
    parameterClasses: Array<Class<*>>, //not nullable
    parameterValues: Array<Any>?
): Any {
    val clazz = target.javaClass
    val method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, *parameterClasses)
    return method!!.invoke(target, parameterValues)
}
```

Comment: Check this https://gist.github.com/ankittale/2ced2beef7222b47308343559b089c19 I had design this class but I don't know how to handle invoke method

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `parameterClasses: Array<Class<*>>?` , try this 
`parameterClasses: Array<Class<*>>`

You cannot use a spread operator on an argument of nullable type.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the spread operator with nullable types, please try removing all the `?` in the function parameters declarations.

```
private fun invokeMethod(
    target: Any,
    methodName: String,
    parameterClasses: Array<Class<*>>, // notnull
    parameterValues: Array<Any> // notnull too
): Any {
    val clazz = target.javaClass
    val method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, *parameterClasses)
    return method!!.invoke(target, *parameterValues) // spread operator needed here too
}
```

Comment: Check this https://gist.github.com/ankittale/2ced2beef7222b47308343559b089c19 I had design this class but I don't know how to handle invoke method

Comment: My impl of `invokeMethod` should compile, what's your current problem? If you see new errors plz show them, it's quite annoying reading that lot of code.